# How to find out which table in the database has the most foreign key references

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have got around 560 tables in my localhost with each and every single table having at least one primary key, foreign key references and for now all of them are empty.

I am starting to insert data into them but, as you have guessed - inserting into any one of these tables would be conflicted by on or the other key.

I am wondering if there is a way to figure out which table has got the highest foreign key references so that I can start inserting into it first. If what I am thinking or my approach sounds completely wrong, please suggest a better way.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sys tables, this will get all the foreign keys:

```
SELECT tables.name as TableName, foreign_keys.name AS ForeignKeyName
FROM sys.foreign_keys
JOIN sys.tables
    ON tables.object_id = foreign_keys.parent_object_id
```

With a slight modification you can get the count of foreign keys per table:

```
SELECT tables.name as TableName, COUNT(*) AS FKCount
FROM sys.foreign_keys
JOIN sys.tables
    ON tables.object_id = foreign_keys.parent_object_id
GROUP BY tables.name
```

However, your task seems slightly different. My suggestion would be to disable all the keys, do your data transfer, then re-enable the keys:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
--Do your data copy here
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```

Note that the re-enabling of keys here is forcing a check on the constraint, this is important otherwise SQL will not trust the foreign key and indexes/performance could be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(Object_name(parent_object_id)) AS cnt,
       Object_name(parent_object_id)        AS table_name
FROM   sys.objects
WHERE  type = 'f'
GROUP  BY Object_name(parent_object_id)
ORDER  BY cnt DESC
```